# How to show contact images in android messaging app

Tags: android, android-listview, xmpp, chat, message

I am creating a messaging app like watsapp and other messaging app.I have implemented messaging and easily able to chat with contacts but now I want to add contact image functionality  to my application so that each contact will be able to upload there image and other user will be able to view contact image when they click on view contact.
Also for each contact view on AppBar I want to show image in circular shape for contact.

Comment: Are you using smack library ?

Comment: Your message  = SMS + Any text message or only text message ?

Comment: Yes I am using smack library. Yes I want to build app similar to wats app with all functionality for now it is just able to chat with other user.But I want each user will be able to view contact image of each other.

Comment: And Also which server you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can achieved by saving the user's contact images to the server .  There is no in-built functionality for storing the images of user inside smack Library so you have to implement that on your own . Send the user's images to the server (e.g. by multipart) and also you would be needing some server-side code to handle the images (saving and providing downloading functionality ).

Comment: I was thinking same way to write my own service to download image depending on authentication.I was looking for if there is already build framework for this procedure.And if you have any experience in building messaging app can you suggest what other technologies should I look into.

Comment: I was having file transfer issues with Openfire and Smack So I used intermediate HTTP server to upload and download images .

Comment: The answer is not correct. XMPP and Smack provide standadized ways for user avatars.

Comment: @Flow Ok . Would you like to share the ways with us. We were not able to find them . Thanks .

Comment: Also , there are little troubles with VCard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838770/how-to-set-get-profile-data-with-xmpp-using-smack

Comment: The answer you mentioned is from 2009. I doubt tnat the issues still exist.

Comment: @Flow : Thanks to tell about VCard. Can you provide any tutorial related to it so that I will able to configure it with my openfire and in my app